# Creating a Factor Generator Program

Tags: java

Okay, so I have been working on this program at school for about a week and I can't seem to figure out why but most numbers work, but for some reason numbers like 36 or 108 don't. I was wondering if anyone could spot out why. Thank you!

```
public class FactorGenerator {
    public FactorGenerator(int a) {
        number = a;
        factor = 2;

    }

    public int nextFactor() // Finds the next factor
    {
        number = (number / factor);
        return factor;

    }

    public boolean hasMoreFactors() // Uses loops and decisions to find if there
                                    // are more factors
    {
        boolean hasMoreFactors = false;
        done = false;
        if (factor < number) {
            while (!done) {
                if (number % factor != 0) {
                    factor++;
                }

                else {
                    done = true;
                    hasMoreFactors = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return hasMoreFactors;
    }

    private int number; // Instance Fields
    private int factor;
    private boolean done;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? If no error, what output do you get? What output do you expect?

Comment: Show how you call these methods

Comment: For 36, this gives `2,2,3,3`. Your desired output is some thing else? These are the factors right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close! You don't need to modify your `number` variable in `nextFactor()`, just increment your `factor` variable:

```
public int nextFactor()
{
    return factor++;
}
```

Making that change, running this:

```
FactorGenerator gen = new FactorGenerator(36);
while (gen.hasMoreFactors())
    System.out.println(gen.nextFactor());
```

yields:

> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 6
>
> 9
>
> 12
>
> 18
>
> 36

This output omits the factor `1`. If you initialize `factor` to `1` in your `FactorGenerator` constructor you'll get the complete factor list.